# How to know when scrollbar position in the end

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have `GridControl` (DevExpress) of form. I want to call some method when position of vertical scrollbar in the end. Is this possible? Thanks.

**EDIT**
My solution(not exactly solve the question, but work great for me):

```
void gvDisplay_TopRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gvDisplay.IsRowVisible(gvDisplay.RowCount - 1) == RowVisibleState.Visible)
    {
        _lastFocusedRowHandle = gvDisplay.RowCount;
        LoadNextPortionOfData();
    }
}
```

Comment: DevExpress comes with a massive documentation. What did you try?

Comment: I saw doc. But, there is no event like ScrollChanged.

Comment: Then at least enlighten us where exactly you looked up stuff. Don't demand from us to do the same errors; always state what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used devexpress before but the way in going about handling this should still be the same or similar regardless as you will still need to create your own extended event. The following is what would be done for the default windows forms, if devexpress extends on this then there should be no problem.

Handling this would be done by an event being triggered. The component class you are using should have a Scroll event, this event is called when the position of the scroll bar changes. If you create a new component class and have it inherit from the component class you want you can then add features that you want. In this new component class you need to extend the event Scroll to check the Value property of the scrollbar. When using this new component class it will still have all the functionality that the original had but now with the new features you added.

For more reading:
Scrollbar class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2htecew.aspx

Scrollbar Scroll event
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.scroll.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it very complex way. I want to find more easly way.

Comment: The process is incredibly easy. To do what you want to do you **will** need to extend an event to call the method. After creating the component class, inheriting from a class is easy as you can see when starting a default windows form 'public partial class Form1 : Form' the ': Form' being tagged on means that Form1 inherits from the Form class. After that extending the event to call a method is like 6 lines of code, most of that being the if statement to check the position of the scroll bar. If devexpress components inherit from the default windows forms then it's all the easier.

Comment: Big thanks for explanation. See how I did it in question, if you interesting.

Comment: Yeah checking to see if the bottom row is visible when there is a change works just the same